# How to use replace for selected strings in a line using python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have data such as

```
Data(str1, str2, str3), Data (2), Data 3, and so on
```

I use the following code to divide the data such that each string after *comma* becomes a new line but the problem here is I *don't* want a new line in between like

```
Data(str1
str2
str3
Data (2)
Data 3
```

But I want my output like

```
Data(str1, str2, str3)
Data (2)
Data 3
```

My code so far:

```
    key_data = str(key_data).replace("[", "")
    key_data = key_data.replace("]", "")
    key_data = key_data.replace("'", "")
    key_data = key_data.replace("(* ","(*,")
```

But this doesn't work my above issue

Comment: What exactly *is* your "data"? Just a big string? If so; why? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without regex just with `split` and `join` :

```
>>> print ')\n'.join(s.split('),'))
Data(str1, str2, str3)
 Data (2)
 Data 3,
```

Comment: @user89 you're welcom !

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print re.split(r",(?![^(]*\))",test_string)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/22

P.S This will not work if you have nested `()` inside `()`.